# Thunderbird, reply-to-all and reply-to-list in one button

Tags: thunderbird, gui

Is it possible to combine "Reply To All" and "Reply To List" buttons in Thunderbird's toolbar? I'd like it to act as "Reply To List" if possible, and as "Reply To All" if I'm not replying to a message from a mailing list.

Comment: Sometimes, one needs the "Reply to All" feature for a mailing list--like if some of the people in the cc: don't subscribe to the list. I don't think combining them makes sense, in that light, so I doubt it has been programmed. Maybe there's a plugin?

Comment: I haven't needed to "Reply to All" in a mailing list for a long time, so the space it takes on my small monitor isn't justified by my usage patterns.

Comment: Yes, can I understand wanting to. But I think it's too niche, unless you can code it up yourself. Sorry I can't offer help, though.

Comment: How about just remove the button all together?  I am sure Thunderbird lets you display which buttons are visible and if not SHAME ON THEM.

Comment: @Remhound: but still both would need to be visible?

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking after, does already exist: The "Smart Reply" button.

It's not in the standard toolbar, but you can add it by customizing the message view toolbar (through right-click on the message view toolbar) and adding the *Smart Reply* button - it does precisely what you want :)

Note: This button only exists in the message view toolbar, not in the main toolbar:

[image: Message view toolbar]

I have a *Smart Reply* button over here:

[image]

Which I can drag and drop to the toolbar, which I did here (and additionally removed the normal *Reply* button):

[image]

Comment: I don't see any button called that way. I guess this might be because I'm actually using Icedove, which currently corresponds to Thunderbird 10…

Comment: This might be the case. I'm seeing some notes about that feature in the [Thunderbird 12 release notes](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/12.0/releasenotes/buglist.html). You could try the [CompactHeader extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/compactheader/) - it also offers a *Smart Reply* button.